# Why is the question asking about guideline on modelling a domain unfocused?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

The question [Is there any guideline on how to choose the objects to be modelled?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/445983/192731) is closed for being unfocused:

> If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format. This can often be fixed by breaking the post into multiple questions, or by focusing on a specific part of the problem.

Can you give more detail why this question has many valid answers but no way to determine which are correct? The already two answers of the question are consensus. The only interpretation to explain the close reason I can think of is the verbose conversation in the question body. I was aware of that, but decided to write it as is anyway because I don't know how to rewrite it without losing the nuances, details, contexts in the conversation. And even so I don't see it worth the effort. I'm looking to hear the opposite thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that stands out is that it appears to be a resource request. Requests for resources, which include books and papers, are off-topic. Although there's enough context clues that you aren't necessarily just looking for links or references or resources, the phrasing may have triggered some of the votes to close.

Setting that aside, the "needs more focus" close reason is also used when the question is so broad that it is likely that the best answers won't fit. Although you have two answers, I don't think they are great answers. There are entire books written about the subject you are asking about - [John Ousterhout's A Philosophy of Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/173210221X), [Eric Evans' Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), [Daniel Jackson's The Essence of Software: Why Concepts Matter for Great Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691230838), and [David Budgen's Software Design: Creating Solutions for Ill-Structured Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138196614) just to name a few. If people can write entire books addressing the question, it is too broad and needs more focus to be answerable on Stack Exchange.

Simply, the fact that you have two answers doesn't mean your question is a good fit. Considering that the answers themselves may not be of the highest quality also points to the question potentially needing revision to ensure it can generate the highest quality, most useful answers to help people in the future.

Comment: Why are requests for resources are off-topic? If I'm looking for a concept, would that count as a request for resource. Also, "people can write entire books addressing the question" doesn't necessarily mean "there is no way to write a focused answer". Books are usually to provide detailed knowledge, while in this case I just need an overview/big picture. What do you think?

Comment: @Ooker Resource requests are off-topic because we, as a community, decided that they are. It's best to use a search engine for things like that. We want to focus on questions that require human experience and knowledge, that can be backed up by providing links or pointers to additional information. We also decided that we, as a community, want focused answers and if you can envision a book being written to answer the question, then the question is too broad. And also such questions tend to be pointers to such books (see why resource requests are off-topic).

Comment: @Ooker: I think you are underestimating the task of "choosing the objects to be modelled", The "big picture" here is that one needs to study the topic at least for a few months or more, practicing it, and in parallel read a few books about it. Moreover, there are a few diffferent schools of thought about the topic.

Comment: @DocBrown what are those different schools of thought?

Comment: @Ooker: at least these two: [Two big schools of Object-Oriented Programming](http://stereobooster.github.io/two-big-schools-of-object-oriented-programming)

Comment: @DocBrown thanks. Nevertheless, don't your comments make a good answer for the question?

Comment: @Ooker: telling someone a question isn't really answerable and that they need to study and practice the topic instead is not a kind of reply I would write into an answer on an SE site. That may be ok for a discussion board, of course, but the SE sites are for Q&As, only the comment sections or the chat rooms are for discussions or meta-explanations.